# How to custom the display content while one node was selected in Plotly Dash

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I have a Plotly Express graph inside a Dash app. Is it possible to customize the content of the hover label (which appears when I move my cursor over a data point)

See image below:

[image]

Comment: external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']
app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "time": ["5-6-1", "5-6-2", "5-6-3","5-6-4"],
    "user": [4, 21, 2, 100],
    "system": [96, 79, 98, 0],
})

fig = px.line(df, x='time', y=['user', 'system'], title='testing ')

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.H1(children='Hello Dash'),

    html.Div(children='''
        Dash: A web application framework for Python.
    '''),

    dcc.Graph(
        id='example-graph',
        figure=fig
    )
])

Comment: Hover text is documented in the Plotly Python Docs: https://plotly.com/python/hover-text-and-formatting/

Comment: great ,thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

okay, it looks like hover_name parameter can be used to resolve this problem.